# combine 4 pictures with ffmpeg to make a square

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, cmd.exe

Please tell me how to combine 4 (1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg) pictures with ffmpeg, 2 above and 2 below them to make a square

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
```

Create batch file

```
ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -i 3.jpg -filter_complex vstack 5.jpg
ffmpeg -i 2.jpg -i 4.jpg -filter_complex vstack 6.jpg
ffmpeg -i 5.jpg -i 6.jpg -filter_complex hstack output.jpg
```

It solves my problem, but maybe there is an easier way?
thanks in advance

Comment: What OS?  32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -i 2.jpg -i 3.jpg -i 4.jpg -lavfi "xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0" out.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageMagick's [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command:

```
montage *.jpg -tile 2x2 result.jpg
```

It will take the first four images and make result-0.jpg, the next four and make result-1.jpg and so on.

[image: not resized]

If you need to resize them:

`montage *.jpg -geometry 375x250+2+2 -tile 2x2 result.jpg`

[image: resized]

[Download](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) ImageMagick

I've purposely made the images blurry.